# Using SoX requires commercial license

Tags: licensing, ffmpeg

I'm building a Linux embedded OS usingYocto in which I have to include SoX to perform downsampling of .wav files.
SoX is under GPL or LGPL license (the downsampling function I use is under LGPL)

When I build my Linux, an error occurs as SoX depends on ffmpeg.
When I add it, another error occurs :

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'ffmpeg' (but /home/myHome/Yocto/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia/recipes-multimedia/sox/sox_14.4.2.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ffmpeg was skipped: because it has a restricted license 'commercial'. Which is not whitelisted in LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST
```

If I set LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST="commercial" in conf/local.conf, as suggested, it builds.

However, I have a question: why using ffmpeg does require "commercial" license, as it is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 2.1 or later (according to https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html)?

How can I avoid to set this flag?

Comment: Exactly which flags did you build ffmpeg with? Specifically, did you use `--enable-nonfree` to [include the Fraunhofer AAC library](https://ffmpeg.org/general.html#OpenCORE_002c-VisualOn_002c-and-Fraunhofer-libraries)?

Comment: well, actually I don't know, there is no information about it popping when I build my Yocto. And I'm far from being a Yocto expert ... I'll try to find it out from logs. But I did not set any flags on my own, I just add ffmpeg in my recipe

Comment: It looks like this flag is used in the ffmpeg_4.4.bb recipe. PACKAGECONFIG[fdk-aac] = "--enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree,--disable-libfdk-aac,fdk-aac" => I suppose it concerns the library you're talking about

Comment: Yeah, that makes ffmpeg include a non-free library so it sounds like the correct behaviour - as the legal page makes clear, the ffmpeg code itself is under the LGPL but it can include/be linked with non-LGPL code. If this answers your question, let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Indeed it answers a part of the question. However it does not seem easy to get rid of it.
Looking into sox recipe I see that it includes ffmpeg in dependencies and there is a line EXCLUDE_FROM_WORLD = "${@bb.utils.contains("LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST", "commercial", "0", "1", d)}"
I guess the constraint of adding "commercial" in whitelist comes from this. 
A way to get rid of ffmpeg will be to compile with the option  --with-ffmpeg=no ... I have to find how to implement this

Comment: From a brief search I believe questions about configuring Yocto are on-topic at [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yocto) so consider asking there - but please review their on-topic guidelines first as I am not an active user there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in comments, your build of FFmpeg was created with the `--enable-nonfree` option which means it [links with the non-free Fraunhofer AAC library](https://ffmpeg.org/general.html#OpenCORE_002c-VisualOn_002c-and-Fraunhofer-libraries), so while you are correct that the FFmpeg code itself is free software, the the combined work is non-free.